# Run Oracle Client in 32-bit mode on a 64-bit machine

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, 32bit-64bit

I have just moved from a 32-bit Windows 7 desktop to a 64-bit Windows 7 Laptop. We have a C# program that we are developing that contains approximately 60 projects within the solution. I keep getting the following error whilst trying to build:

```
Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException. This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed
```

Obviously the error is quite self explanatory and I am trying to get my whole solution to load in 32 bit mode. I have gone through every single project and set the target platform to x86 but I am still getting this error. I have searched Google and seen countless different approaches, but I cant seem to fix this problem. What is the best way to ensure my project is running in 32-bit mode on a 64-bit machine?

I am using Visual Studio 2008. I am currently considering downgrading to 32-bit but really want to avoid having to do this.

Comment: It's not clear - do you get this error during the build process, or when you run the application?

Comment: The build succeeds, but when loading the first page (it's a web based app) it throws this error when trying to connect to the Oracle DB.

Comment: What Oracle client are you using (32-bit or 64-bit)?

Comment: I have both available. But I guess the preference would be 32-bit as that's what has previously worked.

Comment: I found that I had to install the 32-bit Oracle Client (using the installer) for this to work, even though I was running on a 64-bit box.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't really know much about Oracle. Am I ok to just download the client from the website and add the tnsnames file to it and it should work? I've only ever used an already setup client on a shared drive in the past.

Comment: @Joseph - You should be able to download client from Oracle. That is what I have done. Also, I've added an answer you might want to try first that explains how to set 32 or 64 bit IIS mode.

Comment: And when you install don't forget to add .NET components.

Comment: @Belogix That did the job! After two days of trying every combination of everything I could think of, that's fixed it. I owe you, thanks!

Comment: @Joseph - Great, glad I could help. I've expanded my answer below. Could you mark as correct please so that others having this issues can find it more easily? I know I wasted two days when I encountered it and found no resources online!

Comment: @Belogix I now have exactly the same problem editing a SSIS package in Visual Studio. Any ideas?

Comment: I have not tried with SSIS package sorry. Is it the exact same message? Might be worth posting a new question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found that you have to install the 32-bit Oracle client (you can [download the installer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html) from their website) even if you are running on a 64-bit machine.

In addition, during the discussions people were talking about 32-bit mode etc. This is how you can check / set that for an IIS 7 hosted application. You shouldn't need to change this but I have added here for completeness / future reference.

- Launch IIS 7 and expand the server name node.
- Click on **Application Pools** node and find the
  application Pool you are using.
- On the right-hand panel click **Advanced Settings...**
- In the pop-up box that appears check **Enabled 32-Bit Applications** setting which is third option from the top.

Answer (score 5):

You have to change your main .exe file to run only as 32-bit. You can do this in Visual Studio - just change *Platform target* from "Any CPU" to "x86".

If this is not possible, use corflags.exe which forces an existing exe to be a 32-bit application.

Comment: I don't have x86 in the drop down in the toolbar, so I guess I'll have to use corflags.exe. From the page you kindly linked me to, I assume I need to run "CorFlags.exe assembly /32BIT+" What exactly is the assembly value? Thanks.

Comment: assembly - your exe file. In visual studio click right your project, choose properties. select Build tab and on it you have Platform target. In this combo you have Any CPU, x86, x64

Comment: I just read in comments that you are using web application. You can set this in IIS: https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1114/how-to-enable-32-bit-application-pool-iis-7-dedicatedvps.aspx

Comment: I'm using the build in ASP.NET Development Server within Visual Studio. How would I set it in this?

Comment: Look here: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/force-aspnet-development-server-run-32-163751.aspx

Comment: I had a look at that yesterday but I couldn't find any answers on that page unfortunately. The way I read it,is that the process is running in 32 bits? In which case, why am I getting the above error?

Comment: Just change WebDev to IISExpress or IIS.

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with this issue for months now and finally solved it.  I think all the posts are helpful, but I had one missing piece.  I didn't have a Microsoft ODBC for Oracle instance setup for User DSN or System DSN.  I'm working on a Windows 8 machine.  So for me I had to go to the general windows search and type in ODBC and open the ODBC Data Source Administrator (32-bit).  Check to see if you have a Microsoft ODBC for Oracle setup on the User DSN tab or the System DSN tab. If not click on Add and select Microsoft ODBC for Oracle.  Fill out the info for your datasource you are trying to hit and click ok.  Make sure to restart your computer and that is what finally worked for me.  Hope this helps some of you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your main .exe file to run only as 32-bit. You can do this in Visual Studio - just change Platform target from "Any CPU" to "x86".
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In my case 64 bit Oracle client was installed on my machine but still giving same error. So, I have analyse that in my application go to Application right click go to ->Properties->Web tab
and uncheck the "Use IIS Express" option if you are using local IIS Web server.
Problem got solved.