# VS Oracle Client Connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oracle, visual-studio-2013

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233079   Message=Attempt to load Oracle client libraries
>   threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running
>   in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.
>   Source=System.Data.OracleClient

Any suggestion to solve this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538561/run-oracle-client-in-32-bit-mode-on-a-64-bit-machine ?

Comment: Even more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client

Comment: > This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.